# Contract function involving transfer to another contract constantly fails

Tags: istanbul

Tx example: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xbc6ce7fc2aba22bb1b1141d3223369472e55618037f53c0cb25eff526edd88a1

(note Rinkeby network)

Function code:

```solidity
function withdrawBalance() external {
    address nftAddress = address(nonFungibleContract);

    require(
        msg.sender == ownerAddress ||
        msg.sender == nftAddress
    );

    nftAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

owner address: `0x776d658cf9fe5024610c324e8d370182874f12c4`

nft contract fallback function:

```solidity
function() external payable {
    require(
        msg.sender == address(saleAuction)
        ||
        msg.sender == address(siringAuction)
        ||
        msg.sender == address(battlesContract)
        ||
        msg.sender == address(monsterFood)
    );
}
```

monsterFood address is the address of the first contract: `0xa3e13f2f7aab3c86e63495eec5fc3eaeb5e4d2d3` so nft contract should accept the transfer.

This was working fine till the recent Istanbul update. What was changed? Is there any way to make it work?

Edit:

Full contract code:

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./ERC721.sol";
import "./MonsterLib.sol";

contract MonsterFood {

ERC721 public nonFungibleContract;

bool public isMonsterFood = true;

uint32 potionDuration = uint32(6 hours);

event PotionCreated(uint code);
event PotionDeleted(uint code);

constructor(address _nftAddress, address _backendAddress) public {
    ownerAddress = msg.sender;
    ERC721 candidateContract = ERC721(_nftAddress);
    nonFungibleContract = candidateContract;
    backendAddress = _backendAddress;
}

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == ownerAddress);
    _;
}

modifier onlyCore() {
    require(msg.sender == address(nonFungibleContract));
    _;
}

function setTokenContract(address _nftAddress) external onlyOwner
{
    ERC721 candidateContract = ERC721(_nftAddress);
    nonFungibleContract = candidateContract;
}

uint[] public cdPricesGrow = [
    10000 szabo,
    20000 szabo,
    30000 szabo,
    40000 szabo,
    50000 szabo,
    55000 szabo,
    60000 szabo,
    65000 szabo,
    70000 szabo,
    80000 szabo,
    85000 szabo,
    90000 szabo,
    108000 szabo,
    120000 szabo
    ];



uint[] public cdPricesRest = [
    10000 szabo,
    20000 szabo,
    30000 szabo,
    40000 szabo,
    50000 szabo,
    55000 szabo,
    60000 szabo,
    65000 szabo,
    70000 szabo,
    80000 szabo,
    85000 szabo,
    90000 szabo,
    108000 szabo,
    120000 szabo
];


struct Potion {
    uint16 code;
    uint256 priceWei;
    uint8 potionEffect;
    bool exists;
}

uint256 public feedingFee = 5 finney;

function setFeedingFee(uint256 val) external onlyOwner {
    feedingFee = val;
}

address public ownerAddress;

mapping (uint16 => Potion) codeToPotionIndex;

function setOwner(address newOwner) public onlyOwner{
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    ownerAddress = newOwner;
}



function setPotionDuration(uint newDuration) external onlyOwner{
    require(newDuration > 0);
    potionDuration = uint32(newDuration);
}

function createPotion(uint _priceWei, uint _code, uint _potionEffect) external onlyOwner returns(uint) {
    require(_code > 2 && _potionEffect > 0);
    require(_code == uint(uint16(_code)));

    Potion memory _potion = Potion({
        priceWei: _priceWei,
        code: uint16(_code),
        potionEffect: uint8(_potionEffect),
        exists: true
    });

    codeToPotionIndex[uint16(_code)] = _potion;

    emit PotionCreated(_potion.code);
    return _potion.code;
}

function feedMonster(address originalCaller, uint foodCode, uint p1, uint p2, uint p3) onlyCore public payable
returns(uint p1_, uint p2_, uint p3_)
{
    require(foodCode == 1 || foodCode == 2);
    require(originalCaller != address(0));
    bool free = originalCaller == backendAddress;

    MonsterLib.Monster memory mon = MonsterLib.decodeMonsterBits(p1, p2, p3);

    if(foodCode == 1) // grow
    {
        applyGrow(originalCaller, mon, free);
    } 
    else if(foodCode == 2)
    {
        applyCDR(originalCaller, mon, free);
    }

    //applyPotion(_food, mon);

    (p1_, p2_, p3_) = MonsterLib.encodeMonsterBits(mon);
}




function applyCDR(address originalCaller, MonsterLib.Monster monster, bool free) internal
{
    require(monster.cooldownEndTimestamp > now);
    require(monster.cooldownEndTimestamp > monster.cooldownStartTimestamp);
    uint totalPriceWei = cdPricesRest[monster.activeRestCooldownIndex];
    uint totalCdLength = monster.cooldownEndTimestamp - monster.cooldownStartTimestamp;
    uint remainingCdLength = monster.cooldownEndTimestamp - now;

    uint price = 0;
    if(!free)
    {
        price = (10000 * remainingCdLength / totalCdLength) * totalPriceWei / 10000;
        price += feedingFee;
        require(msg.value >= price);
    }

    monster.cooldownEndTimestamp = uint64(now);
    monster.activeRestCooldownIndex = 0;
    monster.activeGrowCooldownIndex = 0;

    originalCaller.transfer(msg.value - price);
}

function applyGrow(address originalCaller, MonsterLib.Monster monster, bool free)  internal 
{
    require(monster.level < 1);
    require(monster.cooldownEndTimestamp > monster.cooldownStartTimestamp);

    uint totalPriceWei = cdPricesGrow[monster.activeRestCooldownIndex];
    uint totalCdLength = monster.cooldownEndTimestamp - monster.cooldownStartTimestamp;

    uint remainingCdLength = 0;
    if(monster.cooldownEndTimestamp > now)
    {
        remainingCdLength = monster.cooldownEndTimestamp - now;
    }

    uint price = 0;

    if(!free)
    {
        price = (10000 * remainingCdLength / totalCdLength) * totalPriceWei / 10000;
        price += feedingFee;
        require(msg.value >= price);
    }

    monster.level = 1;
    monster.cooldownEndTimestamp = uint64(now);
    monster.activeRestCooldownIndex = 0;
    monster.activeGrowCooldownIndex = 0;

    originalCaller.transfer(msg.value - price);

}


function getPotion(uint256 _potionCode)
    external
    view
    returns (
    uint256 priceWei,
    uint256 potionEffect,
    bool exists
) {
    Potion storage _potion = codeToPotionIndex[uint16(_potionCode)];
    require(_potion.exists);
    exists = _potion.exists;
    priceWei = _potion.priceWei;
    potionEffect = _potion.potionEffect;
}


function deletePotion(uint _code) public onlyOwner {
    delete codeToPotionIndex[uint16(_code)];
    emit PotionDeleted(_code);
}

function withdrawBalance() external {
    address nftAddress = address(nonFungibleContract);

    require(
        msg.sender == ownerAddress ||
        msg.sender == nftAddress
    );
    // We are using this boolean method to make sure that even if one fails it will still work
    nftAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
}}
```

Comment: can you paste the entire contract?

Comment: @SamuelDare posted entire contract. Do you think includes might help? I don't think they (and function that use them) are relevant to this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Istanbul update was not backward compatible and broke some contract such as your one.  Here are the details.

```
nftAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
```

Invokes fallback function on “nft” contract providing only 2300 gas for it to consume.

Fallback function of “nft” contract, among other things, reads four values from the storage: `saleAuction`, `siringAuction`, `battlesContract`, and `monsterFood`.

Istanbul fork, among other things, applied [EIP-1884](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1884) which increased gas cost of `SLOAD` operation from 200 to 800.  This operation is used to load values from storage.  So previously, loading four values costed 800 gas and now it costs 3200, which does not fit into 2300 gas.  That's why your contract now fails to work.

Most probably you will not be able to fix already deployed contract, while you may fix the code and redeploy.  Just replace

```solidity
nftAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
```

line with

```solidity
bool status;
(status, ) = nftAddress.call.value(address(this).balance)("");
require (status);
```